# Load balancers for a decoupled web application on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, autoscaling, amazon-elb

I'm not completely familiar with the load balancers in AWS. So, the idea is to set up a VPC with a public subnet and a private subnet. The instances and the ASG for the front-end will be in the public subnet, and the instances and the ASG for the backend will be in the private subnet. My question is which load balancer should I place between the front-end and the backend, and is it supposed to go in the public or the private subnet?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have alb, you don't need any instances in a public subnet. Instead Alb would be there.

Comment: The front end is hosting a react app. Should i move that to the private subnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I recommend you to use **S3 + CloudFront** for your web if its react app ( html,JS...) you can earn a lot with S3 + Cloudfront to have a serveless web hosting high scalable, and security also !!!

Regarding the back end part, the best practice is to put an ELB  in **your public subnet** wich redirect traffic api to your back-end to a target group ASG in your  **private subnet.**

You can add a certificate **https** ACM to your Alb to perform the transit security.
and the traffic from your ALB and instances ASG is in the http (port 80)

Finally the query will come from the client device wich whill get the app from cloudfront/S3 and perform a call to your ELB in public wichi redirect to your instances in private subnet.

Comment: does the s3+cloudfront combo support dynamic websites? cause remember reading somewhere that it only supports static websites. And regarding the ELB, which one specifically, like ALB, NLB, or any other type

Comment: Yes its support Static web site hosting like angular, react js app, In my project i host them in s3 instead of EC2 with nginx... For ELB,  you can use ALB wich is a layer 7 load balancer you can redirect routes follwing path....